# How to debug custom field type?

Tags: custom, field-definition

I wonder if we can debug custom field ? Does "attach to process" method works for custom field?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to debug?

Comment: i developed and deployed a custom field. when i add this custom field as a column to a list, i get some exception. so i want to trace it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can debug the custom field by using the Attach to Process, and attach to your w3wp process for your site.

Alternatively, you can use CKS extensions in Visual Studio, which will attach you automatically.

HTH

Comment: and when does the visual studio hits breakpoint? any time the field rendered? on list item entry and display?

Comment: Any time the field is displayed in the form views. The list views are handled via the XML file, which doesn't debug.

Comment: Actually my main problem is, i cannot get the value of the column that is type of my custom field from code. when looping through list.Fields, when it comes to the index of custom column, it throws exception: "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"

Comment: can you use the field in the list via the browser? Are you converting the value into your field class, or just getting to string? i.e. item["Custom Field"].toString() or new CustomField(item["Custom Field"])?

Comment: Certainly yes. I can use it in the list via browser without any problem.(no prob. in add, edit, display forms) And from the code, i do not convert the value to anything, it throws exception even you assign it to the object type

Comment: Additionally, i tried to browse the list item that contains my custom field from Sharepoint Manager. It also throws the same exception when expanding the related node to browse the properties

Comment: I've recently made a custom field, and we're pulling and pushing from it, so I know it's possible ;) What type of field is it inheriting from? Try grabbing it via PowerShell, see if you get a different error?

Comment: actually the field is this: http://code.google.com/p/sharepoint-treeview-column/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FBrickRed.OpenSource.TreeView%2FHelperFiles

Comment: if i will succeed to use this as-is, i am going to extend it

Comment: I'm not familiar with that field. I perused the code a little and don't see the normal Value property for getting/setting. I'd bet that might be part of the issue? Not sure. Good luck from here!